# Microservices calling other external services

Tags: microservices

My apologies as the realm of this question is very broad. We are starting on a new journey of defining microservices and starting with a DDD (We are based off .NET tech stack but I reckon for purposes of discussion this topic is independent of the stack)

At this moment, we have roughly identified the domains and we have defined layers like Domain Layer, Infrastructure Layer, Application layers. So for example if we have a customer / client we have defined the following layers for like so. The point where we are really getting confused is how this microservice with other service which are not microservice per se. Say for example, if there is a rule that a CreateCustomer command, as a part of its creation, needs CreditScore verfication and if this service is provided by some external provider via a facade that could be written in house, how should a microservice communicate with such a service?

Are there any patterns or any recomendation re how such microservice to other services communication needs to be defined? Any recomendations / suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the question is not very specific. Basically, I am stuck at a point where I need to understand how does a Microservice commnunicate with other existing SOAP based services.

Answer (score 0):

services dependency manager 
+ protocol (REST/RPC/native API's) 
+ circuit breakers

just like any other micro/service would do.

*Don't understand why (external) micro/service is not just another micro/service for your system.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have a external service that we provides us a service and it has been facaded by a SOAP service. My question specifically relates to what are the recommended approaches when designing a Microservice that needs to communicate with such SOAP services. Should it be rest or some sort of event based queue system?